# SQL In Select Statement show values from the same table but different records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a "Students" table with two columns "UserID" and "Name".

Next I have a table named "TestResults" with three columns, UserID, TestID, and TestScore.

I would like to run a single query that shows for each User, on ONE row, their test scores, for tests that have the TestID equal to 1A or 2A.

What approach is the best, I'm wondering if Pivot is the best way or is there another that is more advisable. Thanks.

Comment: hint: INNER JOIN

Comment: It would start with "SELECT". Not trying to be snarky but we are not here to do your (home)work for you. At least show some effort.

Comment: This isn't h.w. I'm trying to learn SQL - anyhow I can do an inner join with TestResults based on the UserID, however how in the select statement, on ONE row do I show test scores for 1A and 2A?

Comment: OK so show some effort on your own. Try something and post it. If you don't try and fail you are going to be learning forever. It is our failed attempts that allow us to learn. Also we don't know what you want for output or what your tables or sample data is like.

Comment: I am guessing that you want to see the results in a single row. You could do this with either PIVOT or conditional aggregation. There are hundreds and hundreds of examples of both of those techniques all over SO and thousands across the rest of the internet.

Comment: Start with a query that have them in separate rows.  Show some effort.

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: Hi Sean Lange, yes I wanted to know what approach is the way to go, if Pivot is the way that is great, I just wanted some feedback from the community for a simple issue like this if Pivot was the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference really. I prefer conditional aggregation over pivot. It is typically slightly better for performance and the syntax is far less obtuse to me. But some people find the syntax for pivot easier for them. In this case it makes little to no difference.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing on your comment, you can use `conditional aggregation` with `max` and `case` to get the results on a single row:

```
select s.userid, s.name, 
    max(case when t.testid = '1a' then t.testscore end) as 1ascore,
    max(case when t.testid = '2a' then t.testscore end) as 2ascore
from students s
    join testresults t on s.userid = t.userid
group by s.userid, s.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
SELECT 
   UserID, 
   TestScore 
FROM 
   TestResults 
WHERE 
   (TestID = 1A) 
OR (TESTID = 2A)
```

Comment: Hi Rahul that would show multiple records, one record per testID, I want to show both test scores on one row per user.

Comment: also you need quotes around `1A` and `2A` and this doesn't use the students table which is needed. It will also require a pivot or conditional aggregation.